# Using an Excel connection file to run queries

Tags: excel, connection-string

I have a large Excel spreadsheet that runs several queries, with the username and password to the source saved within the connection string. I believe that using a standard connection file for all the queries would allow the refreshes to run faster (since each query wouldn't require a separate log-in), but these queries draw from several different tables, and the connection file requires a specific one. Is there a way that I could create an appropriate connection file that would improve the efficiency of these queries?

Comment: This is all a little vague, could you post some of the code you are using (minus the connection string obviously) and a bit more detail (ie what sort of database are you querying). At the moment there could be lots of answers.

Comment: I'm querying an Oracle database. In the connection string section of every workbook connection I have, there is the log-in in formation, which includes my username and password.

The command text runs a select statement across several joined tables. I'm not exactly looking to optimize the code  so much as figure out a way to avoid multiple log-ins.

Comment: That's going to be tricky, as it's probably better (strange as it sounds) to login when you want to run a query and log out when you have your result. Leaving connections open indefinitely could cause you problems, as if your application crashes or is closed in a way that you can't catch and close the connection on the way out will mean the connection stays open, and if this happens enough your database could crash.